# PHP detect if shell_exec() command failed

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I'm running the ffmpeg command within PHP's shell_exec() to convert several videos in a list. Is there anyway to detect if an error happened while the video was being converted (or atleast verify it fully completed the conversion)?

I don't want to stop converting other videos if an error happens, just the ability to record the error.

```
<?php
    shell_exec('ffmpeg -i downloads/flv/file1.flv -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis downloads/webm/file1.webm');

    if(error) {
     //run a command here to report the error (ie. MySQL or email)
    }
?>
```

Comment: are you looking for an error returned from ffmpeg?

Comment: shell_exec returns the output of executed commend, if ffmpeg prints the error you should be able to parse it.

Comment: how to get the error returned from ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Capture the exit code with another system call function like `exec`:

```
exec('ffmpeg ...', $output, $return);

if ($return != 0) {
    // an error occurred
}
```

Any decent utility will exit with a code other than 0 on error.

Comment: Or check if ($return != 1). 1 is an error and 0 is no error exit code. You can debug in the Unix CLI directly with echo "$?" after executing your command.

Comment: Well, `0` means "all green", while *anything other than `0`* means "error". There are more error codes than just `1`. I don't know if `ffmpeg` in particular uses anything besides `0` and `1`.

Answer (score -2):

```
$return=shell_exec('ffmpeg ...');

if ($return) { //look at what it returns do what you will with the data

}
```