# return empty result in run Java inside PHP

Tags: java, php

I wrote a java class with name GetRandomKey.class

I run this file with this command:

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec('java GetRandomKey');
?>
```

This code is run in local (Windows 10 - 64bit)

But I upload in VPS with Windows server 2016 and 64bit.

It doesn't work and it returns an empty result!

I wrote this code `shell_exec('dir')` and its return result. but I can't run `java` command.

I get this Error!

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg`

Comment: make sure java is installed on server and permission is allowed to execute commands form php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP detect if shell\_exec() command failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923876/php-detect-if-shell-exec-command-failed)

Comment: I install Java.  I can run this command in CMD and get the result. but in PHP I can't.

Comment: I can run this command and get result: shell_exec('dir')

Comment: use: `exec("java GetRandomKey 2>&1", $msg);` and then `var_dump($msg)` to show possible errors.

Comment: @jibsteroos I get this Error: Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg

Comment: this might help [running-java-gives-error-could-not-open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036462/running-java-gives-error-could-not-open-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-amd64)

Comment: @jibsteroos No. it doesn't help!